# Mainting a common library among hundreds of small applications

Tags: .net, tfs, architecture, shared-libraries

I have a question about creating a common library for a very large number of small applications.  I joined a development team of 2 recently.  We are about to expand to 3.  We have over 200 applications that we maintain.  All applications support our operations and all are in house development projects.

All of these applications reference a lot of third party dependencies such as dapper, nlog, etc... But none reference a common in house library.

I thought it would be best to wrap these third parties in a façade to allow interchangability and in addition provide common functionality that these applications use such as sending emails, instantiating database connections, etc.  All applications would be modified to reference this library.

I think it helps to add consistency to things like email and logging, however, I don't know how to manage 200 applications referencing a single version of a library.

My original thought was to have all 200 apps reference the same version of the libraries, which would be rebuilt automagically by a CI build when it new one of it's dependencies (libraries) were changed, but from what I'm told this is too risky and not supported by TFS.

Should I allow these 200 applications to all reference various versions of a common library I create, or is it really not worth the trouble and let all applications spin up their own logging, email sending, and audit logic?

If the common library is the best practice for this, how do you keep track of the which application uses which version of the library when bugs are discovered, etc.

---

**Edit to clarify from potential duplicate question**

The potential duplicate question was in regards on how to create a build script that would automatically build projects based on their dependencies being changed.  This question is asking if a common library that would need that sort of building mechanism is appropriate in the first place.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TFS CI Build Chain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33045927/tfs-ci-build-chain)

Answer (score 3):

You presumably keep third-party dependencies like NLog up-to-date using NuGet.

Why not use NuGet for your in-house library as well?  You can setup a private NuGet feed with reasonable effort.

> Some companies restrict which third-party libraries their developers may use. Therefore, they might not want developers to have access to everything in the official NuGet feed, or they might have a set of proprietary libraries they want to make available in addition to the official feed.
>
> In these scenarios, you can set up a custom NuGet feed, and you can configure Visual Studio to offer that feed instead of or in addition to the official feed. A feed can be local (a folder on the local machine or a network folder), or remote (an intranet or internet URL).

Source: [docs.nuget.org](https://docs.nuget.org/create/hosting-your-own-nuget-feeds)

Depending on your comfort level placing your code compiled in an external data center, there are also a number of NuGet service providers listed at the same link.

Comment: We currently use nuget for providing the third party dependencies and have toyed with the idea of using nuget for our library.  However, my concern is with updating 200 application's nuget packages when we need to rollout a bug fix in the library.  It doesn't seem practical to have to open and update 200 applications in tfs to update the packages manually.

Comment: Can't your build server get the latest packages from NuGet when building?